# "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed" #2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm building a simple ASP.NET API using EF and Oracle Database. When I want to get all elements from a database table the response (500) says "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed".

[image]

Well, I've tried to solve this problem before to post it here. But I can't. My Controller Code is as follows.

```
 public class PruebasController : ApiController
 {

    //Prueba[] pruebas = new Prueba[] 
    //{ 
    //    new Prueba { Name = "Tomato Soup"}, 
    //    new Prueba { Name = "Yo-yo"}, 
    //    new Prueba { Name = "Hammer"} 
    //};

    public IQueryable<Prueba> GetAllPruebas()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<OracleDbContext>());

        using (var ctx = new OracleDbContext())
        {
            return ctx.Pruebas;
        }
    }
}
```

(As you see, I have a "pruebas" List and when I return it the http service works)

And this is my **OracleDbContext**

```
public class OracleDbContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Prueba> Pruebas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("DATA");
    }
}
```

Comment: As Brino mentioned in his Answer. Alternatively, you can instantiate your context in your controller (likely during startup) and dispose of it when disposing your  controller. This way, you can keep using your current construct without having to fallback to ToList oid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning an `IQueryable` object. Once you return, you exit your Using statement, which closes your `Context`. You need to enumerate using `.ToList()` before you exit your using statement. This will execute the query while the context is still open.

Change it to this:

```
public List<Prueba> GetAllPruebas()
{
   using (var ctx = new OracleDbContext())
    {
        return ctx.Pruebas.ToList();
    }
}
```

Also, you should add your initializer in the constructor of your context, not your GetAllPruebas method, like this:

```
public class OracleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public OracleDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<OracleDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<OracleDbContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Prueba> Pruebas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("DATA");
    }
}
```

Comment: I just make your suggestion but the error persists.

Comment: please show us the line of code that throws the error.

Comment: When I use toList() instead AsEnumerable() the error changes. 

The DropCreateDatabaseAlways initializer did not drop or create the database backing context 'OracleDbContext' because Migrations are enabled for the context. Use Migrations to manage the database for this context, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.

Comment: I think that is a "context" problem, I just write a insert statement and when I add the object "pruebas" to the context object, it throws this error : 

"The DropCreateDatabaseAlways initializer did not drop or create the database backing context 'OracleDbContext' because Migrations are enabled for the context. Use Migrations......"

Comment: Correct, it can't initialize your DB, so there is nothing to create a context for.

Comment: Looks like EF6 initially prevented you from using initializers and migrations at the same time. The newest version might remove this restriction, but until then CreateDatabaseIfNotExists should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78949/discussion-between-brino-and-ivan-casanova).

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved. I wrote  **CreateDatabaseIfNotExists** instead **DropCreateDatabaseAlways** in the Database.SetInitializer and it works.